# Is it possible to use google maps without using a callback?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'd like to have google maps loop through a bunch of cities while doing a nearby search. However, the asynchronous strategy from maps is not allowing the code to operate as intended. I want it to be procedural and it seems like removing the callback would fix it.

Does anyone have advise?

Comment: can we see some code please?

Comment: http://eurothermwindows.com/ed/test.ba.php You can see in the table that the counter is being incremented to the number 3 before 2. I assume it's something with the asynchronous parts of the api.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the answer has to be **NO**

The Maps-API internally uses a lot of async-requests, for example the loading of the tiles is the result of the callback of an asynchronous request.

But the issue here are not asynchronous requests at all, it's asynchronous requests to services(geocoding, places).

When I redefine the question to :

**Is it possible to use responses of google maps services without using a callback?**
The answer has to be: **YES**

These webservices may be accessed from serverside too, so you may get the results on serverside and pass them to the scripts directly.

Another option would be a **synchronous** request to the webservices, but in practice this would block the browser until you get the response, that's not a desirable option.